# There a simple way to find formulas that give the sum of series?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I was wonder if there exists a simple method to find the sum of series by deriving a formula for that sum, this applying to all types of sums, not just the sum of a polynomial like sum of the first 100 n elements, etc.

Example.

$ \sum_{n=1}^{100} sin(n) $

I am unfamiliar with this particular sum, and I don't have the time to sit down and figure it out.

I am curious is there exists methods to allow us to derive formulas that give us the sum of these series.

I've been using the systems of equations method for sums of polynomial series and thats fine and easy but my biggest concern is again, non-polynomial series that are being summed.

I'm looking for a good and useful method, or a even a book that will explain a branch of mathematics that will help me in solving problems like this.

Thank you!

Comment: For this particular problem, you can use the fact that $\sin n=\frac1{2i}((e^i)^n-(e^{-i})^n)$ to compute this easily as a sum of two geometric series.

Comment: For some sums, there do exist formulas. For example, the sum, $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. It really just depends on the sum that you are asking about.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I'm not really familiar with that, I forget stuff like that, I mean, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: When it comes to summing series, there is a bag of tricks which work in specific cases, but no general method that works all the time.  Some series simply have no "closed-form" sum in terms of familiar functions.

Comment: @awkward I've heard about generator functions and stuff like that, is that worth looking into to help solve problems like these?

Comment: By all means, generating functions are useful and IMHO, one of the Big Ideas in mathematics.  One good introductory book is "generatingfunctionology" by Wilks.  You can find the book in pdf for free, online.  Or many books on combinatorics include introductions to generating functions.

Comment: Among the "bag of tricks" one can consider 2 tricks that are more than tricks  : a) The powerful Gosper algorithm for summing certain types of (so-called hypergeometric) series : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm b) by the transformation of summation into integrals, using the very powerful theorem of residues in complex analysis.

Comment: @awkward so, geneatoring functionology is a good way to learn how to derive formulas for the sum of series?

Comment: Yes, quite often a generating function can be used to sum a series.

Comment: @awkward Oh, thats perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @JeanMarie Someone said a method is a trick you have applied twice. ;-)

Comment: "I don't have the time to sit down and figure it out" ... seem to be the biggest hurdle to overcome.

Comment: @awkward I appreciate.